# Importing 3d model in three.js at runtime from localfile

Tags: javascript, three.js, localhost, same-origin-policy

I am trying to upload a 3d model from local file in runtime, but facing CORS error message. I have used http-server for uploading fixed models at start, but if I want to upload random objects from my local files to the scene, what is the best method to avoid CORS error?

For loading, I have used "OBJLoader" from https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/OBJLoader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a drag'n'drop approach similar to the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) to load files from your computer into the app. The idea is to add an event listener to the `drop` event, extract the files from the respective event object and then use `FileReader` to read the actual content. When this loading process has finished, you can directly use `OBJLoader.parse()` in order to create the actual 3D objects.

Check out the following code sections of the editor to better understand this workflow.

- Handle `drop` event.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/b524f4bca95169a2b197f8a68058e6c28abf416d/editor/index.html#L284-L290

- Process the file list since it's possible to drag'n'drop multiple objects at once.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/b524f4bca95169a2b197f8a68058e6c28abf416d/editor/js/Loader.js#L12-L43

- Use `FileReader` and the respective loader (in your case `OBJLoader`) to load and parse the actual file. The linked method handles many different 3D formats. Just search for the `OBJ` part.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/b524f4bca95169a2b197f8a68058e6c28abf416d/editor/js/Loader.js#L45

`three.js R104`

Answer (score 0):

I follow the proposed solution and for allow the system to work I add the following part:

```
document.addEventListener("dragover", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31451806)